# Human gene number distribution on different strands of the chromosomes

Tags: genetics, transcription, human-genome

I cannot find an article that describes the gene distribution based on their appearances on different strands and if I find one, like [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3614620/) from 2007, there are some aspects which are confusing, for instance:

> A total of 12,692 loci were present on the positive strand, with
> 12,442 on the negative strand.

How are positive and negative strands determined in general if we are not talking about a particular gene at a particular locus?

Aren't both strands similar in a way that we can not name one as a sense, antisense, template, or coding? Are not both strands in a chromosome used for transcription in a symmetric way?

Any article related to my main question (in the headline) or explanation about this confusion in this article would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For humans and other eukaryotes, the convention is that the "start" of each chromosome is the end closest to the centromere:

> In all human reference chromosomes, as for other eukaryotes [3], the plus (+) strand is defined as the strand with its 5′ end at the tip of the short arm [4,5] (Genome Reference Consortium, personal communication, March 27, 2012).

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6099125/